# Loadash sortby Alphabetically

Tags: javascript

Loadash default sortby function sorts the data by ASCII characters. It causes trouble when sorting is done between lowercase and uppercase strings.

```
 filteredData = _.sortBy(filteredData, sortByField);
```

Here filteredData is an array of objects. I just debugged into the sortby method where i could see, internally an array is formed with only the column which needs to be sortedby..

In otherwords, i have filtereddata, which has columns as col1,col2, col3,col4... based on the sortbyField, in the loadash.js file, an internal array is formed.. say for example, if i wanna sortby col3,an array is formed with col3 and then sorting is performed..

I was thinking to include toLowerCase in the loadash file but since its not advisable, i havent done it.

Another option is, i have to convert by entire object into lowercase, i believe it will overhead.

Can someone provide me the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
_.sort(filteredData, function (a, b) {
  var col1a = a.col1.toLowerCase();
  var col1b = b.col1.toLowerCase();
  if (col1a === col1b) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (col1a > col1b) {
    return 1;
  }
  return -1;
});
```

or fancy:

```
var modArg = function (arg) {
  return arg.col1.toLowerCase();
};

var compare = _.modArg(function (a, b) {
  if (a === b) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  }
  return -1;
}, modArg, modArg);

_.sort(filteredData, compare);
```

Comment: here the filteredData is an array and also sortfield(col1) is dynamic one.
Also i m using _sortBy of loadash... i m fine with getting rid of loadash but is there any option which i can use with loadash itself?

Comment: Sorry the code should have read _.sortBy. You can change the compare function to what ever works for your case. The one I wrote does a lowercase compare of the col1 prop, but you can modify it to what you need